# Rotate decision tree branches according to values of terminal nodes with ggparty

Tags: r, ggplot2, decision-tree, party

I'm plotting decision trees built with `partykit` in `ggparty`, and struggling to rotate the tree branches around branch nodes- as in, change the order they are displayed. I'm hoping to plot a tree with the branches displayed in an order according to the values of the terminal nodes. This would be somewhat comparable to using `reorder()` in a standard `ggplot` geom.

For instance, outlined below using the WeatherPlay data from the [ggparty vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggparty/vignettes/ggparty-graphic-partying.html), can the branches of this tree be rotated so that terminal node geom_bar() plots are displayed in increasing order of proportion "yes"? In this case, this would mean "sunny", then "rainy", then "overcast".

For my project I'll have terminal nodes with boxplots, but I'm guessing that the method for rotating branches is modular and can be repurposed.

```
## Playing with default WeatherPlay data as demonstrated in ggparty examples here:
# https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggparty/vignettes/ggparty-graphic-partying.html
library(partykit)
library(ggparty)
data("WeatherPlay", package = "partykit")
sp_o <- partysplit(1L, index = 1:3)
sp_h <- partysplit(3L, breaks = 75)
sp_w <- partysplit(4L, index = 1:2)
pn <- partynode(1L, split = sp_o, kids = list(
  partynode(2L, split = sp_h, kids = list(
    partynode(3L, info = "yes"),
    partynode(4L, info = "no"))),
  partynode(5L, info = "yes"),
  partynode(6L, split = sp_w, kids = list(
    partynode(7L, info = "yes"),
    partynode(8L, info = "no")))))
py <- party(pn, WeatherPlay)

# Node plots
n1 <- partynode(id = 1L, split = sp_o, kids = lapply(2L:4L, partynode))
t2 <- party(n1,
            data = WeatherPlay,
            fitted = data.frame(
              "(fitted)" = fitted_node(n1, data = WeatherPlay),
              "(response)" = WeatherPlay$play,
              check.names = FALSE),
            terms = terms(play ~ ., data = WeatherPlay)
)
t2 <- as.constparty(t2)

# Plot tree
ggparty(t2) +
  geom_edge() +
  geom_edge_label() +
  geom_node_splitvar() +
  geom_node_plot(gglist = list(geom_bar(aes(x = "", fill = play),
                                        position = position_fill()),
                               xlab("play")),
                 # draw only one label for each axis
                 shared_axis_labels = TRUE,
                 # draw line between tree and legend
                 legend_separator = TRUE
  )
```

[image]